# Why is a Exception in thread "FileWatchdog" java.lang.NullPointerException and how do I fix it?

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, exception

I was unsure of why my project will be such an exception, I also do not know the reason

my project environment are springmvc and hibernate build instead controlled by 
maven .
The pom.xml file is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.cnleyao.cardvoucher</groupId>
    <artifactId>cardvoucher</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cardvoucher Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
        <jackson.version>2.5.0</jackson.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- spring core jar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 使用SpringMVC需配置 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 关系型数据库整合时需配置 如hibernate jpa等 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 二级缓存ehcache -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- c3p0数据源 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- mysql连接 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- aop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 阿里巴巴的开源数据库连接池druid -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- springmvc文件上传功能所依赖的组件 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 用于邮件发送的jar包 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>cardvoucher</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <!-- generate java doc -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <javadocDirectory>target/javadoc</javadocDirectory>
                    <reportOutputDirectory>target/javadoc</reportOutputDirectory>
                    <charset>UTF-8</charset>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <docencoding>UTF-8</docencoding>
                    <show>private</show>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**For more information about the exception is above**

> Exception in thread "FileWatchdog" java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(WebappClassLoader.java:1542)
>         at javax.xml.parsers.SecuritySupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at javax.xml.parsers.SecuritySupport.getResourceAsStream(Unknown Source)
>         at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findJarServiceProvider(Unknown Source)
>         at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(Unknown Source)
>         at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:854)
>         at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:755)
>         at org.apache.log4j.xml.XMLWatchdog.doOnChange(DOMConfigurator.java:1125)
>         at org.apache.log4j.helpers.FileWatchdog.checkAndConfigure(FileWatchdog.java:89)
>         at org.apache.log4j.helpers.FileWatchdog.run(FileWatchdog.java:108)

```
  /*
```

* Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 * contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 * this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 * The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 * (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 * the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 * 
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * 
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

// Contributors:  Mathias Bogaert

```
package org.apache.log4j.helpers;

import java.io.File;

/**
   Check every now and then that a certain file has not changed. If it
   has, then call the {@link #doOnChange} method.


   @author Ceki G&uuml;lc&uuml;
   @since version 0.9.1 */
public abstract class FileWatchdog extends Thread {

  /**
     The default delay between every file modification check, set to 60
     seconds.  */
  static final public long DEFAULT_DELAY = 60000; 
  /**
     The name of the file to observe  for changes.
   */
  protected String filename;

  /**
     The delay to observe between every check. By default set {@link
     #DEFAULT_DELAY}. */
  protected long delay = DEFAULT_DELAY; 

  File file;
  long lastModif = 0; 
  boolean warnedAlready = false;
  boolean interrupted = false;

  protected
  FileWatchdog(String filename) {
    super("FileWatchdog");
    this.filename = filename;
    file = new File(filename);
    setDaemon(true);
    checkAndConfigure();
  }

  /**
     Set the delay to observe between each check of the file changes.
   */
  public
  void setDelay(long delay) {
    this.delay = delay;
  }

  abstract 
  protected 
  void doOnChange();

  protected
  void checkAndConfigure() {
    boolean fileExists;
    try {
      fileExists = file.exists();
    } catch(SecurityException  e) {
      LogLog.warn("Was not allowed to read check file existance, file:["+
          filename+"].");
      interrupted = true; // there is no point in continuing
      return;
    }

    if(fileExists) {
      long l = file.lastModified(); // this can also throw a SecurityException
      if(l > lastModif) {           // however, if we reached this point this
    lastModif = l;              // is very unlikely.
    doOnChange();
    warnedAlready = false;
      }
    } else {
      if(!warnedAlready) {
    LogLog.debug("["+filename+"] does not exist.");
    warnedAlready = true;
      }
    }
  }

  public
  void run() {    
    while(!interrupted) {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(delay);
      } catch(InterruptedException e) {
    // no interruption expected
      }
      checkAndConfigure();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is this all of the exception trace?

Comment: @Chirag Senjallya Yes ,you can help me to solve

Comment: Can you show `FileWatchdog.java`

Comment: @wanghao Please use NIO2 to get notified when a file has changed.

Comment: @Michael-O you can say specific operation steps,please, i don't really understand what you said NIO2